# Panel problem on Toshiba Satellite c855-2gd

Tags: 12.04, panel, toshiba-satellite

I'm currently using ubuntu 12.04 (LTS) and I'm facing an issue with this distro. First of all, I've heard that problems with ubuntu on **toshiba satellite** laptops often occur. Don't know whether it has something with toshiba drivers or something else, but there are other operational systems facing the problem when installed on a toshiba laptops.

I am using a [toshiba satellite c855-2gd](http://www.toshiba.com/us/computers/laptops/satellite/C850/C855-S5345). With its system components, I see no reason for ubuntu being dysfunctional.

However at times, when I download an app from Ubuntu Software Center, during the installation my side and top panel just disappear. Then I am unable to do anything ( not even open terminal via ctrl+alt+T ) but to go for that black screen on crtl+alt+f6 and reboot my system. Then my panels are back but I'm bit frustrated that my panels are often missing. Just a few moments ago, I downloaded a presentation ( pptx format ) and it happened again! And it happened a week ago when I was transmitting data from my USB to my laptop...

Once I managed to install a wine application on my ubuntu, I tried to run the old game ( Diablo 1 ) and the whole system crashed!

Can someone please tell me what to do to prevent such problems in future? And would it somehow help if I upgrade to ubuntu 13.10 ? Perhaps there are some features in 13.10 release that I don't know of and could help with this annoying panel problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to suggest you run from a LiveUSB w/ 13.10 for a week. It will launch a little slower, but you can still access your documents on the HDD as needed. If, after a week, the system is stable, then wither upgrade the OS or reinstall 12.04. What I suspect is a write error during the original install, not a defect in the hardware.

Comment: I decided to switch to ubuntu 13.10 entirely.It works even better now and I am no longer experiencing panel problem. I noticed that my graphical driver is no longer listed as "unknown", so probably the graphical driver was the issue, I guess...

Comment: If you click on the checkmark-in-circle at left, it shows others the solution works and adds to your karma on this board.